# PHP Native client driver doesn't want to drop index created with SQLCMD

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I created a database from SQL scripts that I ran with SQLCMD and also with some scripts into SSMS. I ran them under the same SQL database user.

When I want to drop an index with PHP script running on IIS with sqlsrv driver, I got an 3701 error (index doesn't exist or not enough permission). I'm sure that the index exists.

I included my SQL database user into sysadmin, db_ddladmin, db_owner.

I tried to grant ALTER permission to my database user according to SQL Server documentation about dropping index. I tried some other grant to I read on this site to enable dropping index. Here is my code:

```
GRANT CONTROL ON dbo.minutes_clients TO admin_igreffe

GRANT ALTER (representant) ON dbo.minutes_clients TO admin_igreffe

GRANT CREATE TABLE TO admin_igreffe

GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA :: dbo TO admin_igreffe
```

Nothing to help me. I checked permission on my table with:

```
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions('dbo.minutes_clients', 'OBJECT')
```

I got the following result:

```
entity_name             subentity_name                      permission_name
----------------------- ----------------------------------- ----------------
dbo.minutes_clients                                         SELECT                            
dbo.minutes_clients                                         UPDATE
dbo.minutes_clients                                         REFERENCES
dbo.minutes_clients                                         INSERT
dbo.minutes_clients                                         DELETE
dbo.minutes_clients                                         EXECUTE
dbo.minutes_clients                                         RECEIVE
dbo.minutes_clients                                         VIEW CHANGE     TRACKING
dbo.minutes_clients                                         VIEW DEFINITION
dbo.minutes_clients                                         ALTER
dbo.minutes_clients                                         TAKE OWNERSHIP
dbo.minutes_clients                                         CONTROL
dbo.minutes_clients     id_minute                           SELECT
dbo.minutes_clients     id_client                           SELECT
dbo.minutes_clients     representant                        SELECT
dbo.minutes_clients     id_minute                           UPDATE
dbo.minutes_clients     id_client                           UPDATE
dbo.minutes_clients     representant                        UPDATE
dbo.minutes_clients     id_minute                           REFERENCES
dbo.minutes_clients     id_client                           REFERENCES
dbo.minutes_clients     representant                        REFERENCES

(21 affected row(s))
```

The index that I want to drop is on representant column. I see that I don't have ALTER permission on that specific column. Is it the problem? How can I do that with SQL script?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after  2-4 days of tests and researches. The problem has nothing to do with permission. I should post the SQL query that I used to drop my index:

```
DROP INDEX fki_minutes_clients_representant_fkey ON minutes_clients.representant
```

This is the problem. My query do not point out on fki_minutes_clients_represenant_fkey index on minutes_clients table on representant column. Thus, the error message that I got was right but ambiguous: cannot find the index (right!) or your don't have the permission to drop this index (wrong!).

Here is the correct syntax that I should use to drop my index:

```
DROP INDEX minutes_clients.representant
```

or

```
DROP INDEX fki_minutes_clients_representant_fkey ON minutes_clients
```

Hope it will be useful for someone